# How to get auto complete suggestions on IDE while developing chrome extension using chrome api?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

recently i am developing chrome extension. using js,html,css however for every action i am searching google for chrome.* api reference. is there any way to add extension for auto complete of chrome.* api methods in vscode?

Comment: Yes, it depends on your IDE. For ManifestV2 you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/chrome and for ManifestV3 use the official https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-types

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 10):

If you use Vscode, just create or update jsconfig.json at the root of project :

```json
{"typeAcquisition": {"include": ["chrome"]}}
```

Comment: For reference, here are the VSCode docs for `jsconfig.json`: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig

Answer (score 2):

Just install the official types provided from the source code itself and you should be good to go.

For example: `npm install --save-dev chrome-types`

Here's the package itself: https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-types

Answer (score 1):

Reference (User: ewwink): https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/93c2ez/chrome_extension_autocomplete/

Steps:

1. Visual Studio Code
2. File => Preferences => Settings
3. User
4. Extensions
5. Under Activation on Language => click on `settings. JSON`
6. Add the following inside the JSON

{"typeAcquisition": {"include": ["chrome"]}}

7. Voila you're ready !

[image: File => Preferences => Settings]

[image: settings. JSON => insert code (:]